# Could not install Dapper 2.0.4 on .Net 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dapper, .net-4.6.1

I'm trying to install Dapper 2.0.4 via nuget manager as i want to use the latest Dapper.Contrib features
It didn't proceed due to the following error:

Could not install package 'Dapper 2.0.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

If i install the lower version (1.6), the installation went successful but i can't use the latest Contrib features.

How can i resolve this?

Hoping for your kind help. Thank you.

Comment: upgrade your .net framework version to 4.7.1 for compatability.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for your response but the problem still exist.

Could not install package 'Dapper 2.0.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I checked my current version, i have the latest 4.7 framework

Comment: @christinesarsonas Try  clearing NuGet cache by going to Tools->Options->NuGet Package Manager-> Clear All NuGet Cache(s)

Comment: Hi @MohsinMehmood i can't locate the 'Clear All NuGet Cache' portion.
I'm currently using VS2015

Comment: @christinesarsonas You can download nuget.exe from `https://www.nuget.org/downloads` and then run the command `nuget locals all -clear`

Comment: Hi @MohsinMehmood thank you for providing the nuget apps to clear my cache. But the problem still exist. Appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Install .Net Framework SDK version 4.7.1 minimum.
2. Select installed target as a Target Framework for all Projects in your Solution (in Project properties).
3. Retarget all packages in all projects executing `update-package -reinstall -ignoreDependencies` from the Package Manager Console.
4. Install Dapper.

UPDATE (from comments):

Dapper needs .NET Standard 2.0. Please retry the whole procedure including re-targeting with .NET Framework 4.7.2 as this is the first fully compliant with. Source: weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Feb/19/

Comment: Hi @Megrez
I reinstall the .Net Framework 4.7.1  and tried to create a sample project under this framework but problem still exist.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not install package 'Dapper 2.0.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Dapper needs .NET Standard 2.0. Please retry the whole procedure including re-targeting with .NET Framework 4.7.2 as this is the first fully compliant with. Source: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Feb/19/Using-NET-Standard-with-Full-Framework-NET#the-first-version-that-fully-net-standard-20-compliant-is-472

Comment: Hi @Megrez if i reinstall my whole .net framework, would that make impact on my other projects? I'm kinda worried that some of my projects won't work or might have problems.

Comment: @christinesarsonas No, until you do not uninstall the old ones. Number of different versions of .NET Framework can exist simultaneously on the system. Install 4.7.2, then change target Framework for every project within your solution to 4.7.2, then retarget all packages. Finally install Dapper 2.0.4.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Megrez, ill finish my other projects then install 4.7.2 in order not to messed up with my other projects. I'll provide feedback once i'm done with it. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the following and it worked for me.

1. Check Target Framework by right-clicking on the project and selecting the Application tab. If the target framework is .NET framework 4.6.1
   `Install-Package Dapper -Version 2.0.4` works fine.
2. If the target framework is less than 4.6.1 (In my case another project has target framework 4.5.2) try installing previous versions of Dapper for example:`Install-Package Dapper -Version 1.50.2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

1. Go to "Tools > NuGet Package Manager > NuGet Manager Settings > Package Sources
2. Once in Package Sources, set name to "Package Source" and Source to "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Dapper/" then update to save
3. Install .Net Framework SDK version 4.7.1 minimum.
4. Select installed target as a Target Framework for all Projects in your Solution
   (in Project properties).
5. Retarget all packages in all projects executing update-package -reinstall -
   ignoreDependencies from the Package Manager Console.
6. Install Dapper.

That should do it for you.